# using expectLastCall in easyMock

Tags: unit-testing, testing, easymock

I want to test how often a method was called.
Im using EasyMock. This is what I have atm.

```
    @TestSubject
    Account account = new Account("acc");

    @Mock
    CheckoutMethod checkoutMethod;
    @Mock
    CheckoutMethod checkoutMethod2;

    @Test
    void test_account () {

        List<CheckoutMethod> methods = new ArrayList<>();

        Item item1 = new Item(1.);

        expect(checkoutMethod.pay(item1)).andReturn(true);
        expect(checkoutMethod2.pay(item1)).andReturn(true); 

        replay(checkoutMethod);
        replay(checkoutMethod2); 

        methods.add(checkoutMethod);
        methods.add(checkoutMethod2); 

        account.setCheckoutMethods(methods);

        boolean should_work = account.checkoutFor(item1);
        Assertions.assertTrue(should_work);
        verify(checkoutMethod, expectLastCall().times(1));
        verify(checkoutMehtod2, expectLastcall().times(0)); 
}
```

the last part is critical and what I want to check.
Im using `verify(checkoutMethod, expectLastCall().times(1));` to check if the method is called once and `verify(checkoutMehtod2, expectLastCall().times(0));` to verify that the method hasn't been called once.

Can this be done this way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not mockito, it's EasyMock. EasyMock will require a recording and the `verify()` will verify all the expectations at once.

So, in your case, not called means not recorded. So you test becomes this:

```
Item item1 = new Item(1.0);

expect(checkoutMethod.pay(item1)).andReturn(true);

replay(checkoutMethod, checkoutMethod2);

List<CheckoutMethod> methods = Arrays.asList(checkoutMethod, checkoutMethod2);

account.setCheckoutMethods(methods);

boolean should_work = account.checkoutFor(item1);
assertTrue(should_work);

verify(checkoutMethod, checkoutMethod2);
```